# Disable Debugging in Expo For React Native App

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

So I've opened up my react-native app in Expo today (using the iOS simulator) and I am creating by what looks like a debugging overlay.

Screenshot here:
[image]

I don't need this and it's blocking some of the UI for testing.

How does one turn it off?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You have the **Element Inspector** open. To toggle it off do either:

- `⌘+D` if you are in the simulator
- Shake your phone if you are on an actual device

This should open up the debugging menu. You can then click on `Toggle Element Inspector` to close it.

[image: Expo Debugging Menu]

Comment: For Android it is ```ctrl+M```

Comment: cmd + d is no longer the way to shake device. it's ^+cmd+z

Answer (score 9):

First you need to open **Debug Menu** ,go to: **Device -> Shake** or **^+⌘+Z**
then inside debugger menu press **Hide inspector**