# Building ios simulator app via expo has made app unclickable due to "Tap something to inspect it"

Tags: react-native, expo

I didn't make any changes to my build environment, or how I'm interacting with my IOS build, but all of a sudden I can't click on anything in the ios simulator bc of this dialogue:

[image]

Basically this little inspector overrides any click action I actually want to test natively in the app.

I'm running via `npx expo run:ios`

Simulation is running on iPhone SE (3rd generation) - iOS 16.4

Attaching my package.json. I may have just accidentally toggled an ios simulator debug option, but i restarted my machine and this still persists despite 0 dependency changes. so I am admittedly very confused. Googling this exact behavior results in no usable references so apologies if this is a boneheaded obvious mistake I made.

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.10",
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "^2.2.5",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^10.0.1",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.9",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "expo": "~49.0.7",
    "expo-constants": "^14.4.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "^2.4.6",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-image": "^1.3.2",
    "expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-modules-autolinking": "^1.5.0",
    "expo-router": "2.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.4.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.3.2",
    "http": "0.0.1-security",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "metro": "^0.76.7",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.9",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-track-player": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.2.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.0.0-0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.0.0-0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties": "^7.0.0-0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals": "^7.0.0-0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.22.10",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.197",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.20",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.72.2",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.18.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.62.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.62.0",
    "confusing-browser-globals": "^1.0.11",
    "eas": "^0.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.47.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-import-resolver-node": "^0.3.9",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-no-date-parsing": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-no-relative-import-paths": "^1.5.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~49.0.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "react-refresh": "~0.14.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react-refresh": "~0.14.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "pnpm": {
    "overrides": {
      "semver@>=7.0.0 <7.5.2": ">=7.5.2"
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if any other build type files would be helpful.

Comment: It is the `Element Inspector` for simulator in React Native. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/45616585/20002061](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45616585/20002061)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this fixed it, but clicking

Device > Erase all contents and settings

then re-running `npx expo run:ios` made this menu go away. :shrug_emoji: